# QRegExp for extracting single line comments from code

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

I have to extract single-line comments from `qmake` project file.
Rules are simple: comment begins with `#` symbol and begin with line-break `\n`.
So i'm read some documentation about `QRegExp`, and write such code to print all comments in qmake file:

```
QRegExp re ("#(.*)\n$");
re.setMinimal (true);
int comment_index = 0;
while ((comment_index = _project_contents.indexOf (comment_expr, comment_index)) != -1)
{
    QString comment_text = comment_expr.cap (0);
    qDebug() << "Comment 1" << comment_text;
}
```

But it is not work correctly - just all contents of project file has been printed.
Where is my mistake? as i understand from docs, this should work, but it doesn't.

P.S. I'm a newbie in regexes, so please don't beat me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.` ["matches any character (including newline)."](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qregexp.html). And the `$` is the end of the string.

You could try using not-newline - `[^\n]` and changing the `$` to `(\n|$)` (newline or end of string):

```
"#[^\n]*(\n|$)"
```

But then this matches `#` anywhere instead of just at the start of a line, so let's try this:

```
"(^|\n)#[^\n]*(\n|$)"
```

`^` is the start of the string, so basically `(^|\n)` (start of string or new line) is just before the start of a line.

Can you see a problem there? What if you have 2 comments in 2 consecutive lines? You'll only match the first, since the new-line will be consumed during matching the first (since the next match starts where the previous one finished).

A work-around for this is using look-ahead:

```
"(^|\n)#[^\n]*(?=\n|$)"
```

This causes the end newline to not be included in the match (but it is still checked), thus the position will be just before the new-line and the next match can use it.

Can the `#` be preceded by spaces? If so, check for zero or more spaces (`\s*`):

```
"(^|\n)\s*#[^\n]*(?=\n|$)"
```

Comment: Thanks! last version of your regex is what i need to. By the way, can you suggest some nice examples/books about `QRegExp`? i need to deeply undestand them because of heavy use.

Comment: I don't have any must-have recommendations. Regex follows a standard syntax (with some minor variations), so any tutorial should be fine. [This (specific to QT)](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qregexp.html#details) has an introduction and recommends "Mastering Regular Expressions (Third Edition) by Jeffrey E. F. Friedl". [Here's also a website I sometimes link to](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). Or you can just check a few of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=introduction+to+regular+expressions) out.

Comment: Thanks again, i will see this materials.
P.S. I hope what i will never be forced to parse HTML with regex's :)

Comment: If you ever find yourself needing / wanting to parse HTML with regex, you should read [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) first.

Comment: I understand what it is ugly way. But for replacing contents of `<a bla-bla/>` to `<a>bla-bla</a>` regex is working fine - just for example.

Comment: @Dukeling: +1 for 'Mastering Regular Expressions'